# entry_submission_start does not fire as expected

Tags: extension, hook

I am trying to use the `entry_submission_start` hook to be able to check the current settings before the extension updates them. I expected the hook to fire before the entry is submitted, but when I query the database, it has already been updated. Here is my code for the extension:

```
function functionName($entry_id, $meta, $data) {
    $query = mysql_query(“SELECT field_id_34 FROM exp_channel_data WHERE entry_id = ‘“.$entry_id.”’”);
    $assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    echo $assoc[‘field_id_34’];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `entry_submission_start` hook doesn't pass an `$entry_id`, because the entry should not have been saved yet. It only passes a `$channel_id` and a boolean value for `$autosave`. ([Docs.](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/index.html#entry-submission-start))

I see your function (which is presumably the function you've installed as the callback for `entry_submission_start` in your extension) is expecting three parameters (`$entry_id, $meta, $data`), which are actually the arguments that are passed `entry_submission_end`.

Are you inadvertently using the wrong hook?

**UPDATE:** I will also echo Justin's sentiment that you should be using EE/CodeIgniter functions to perform database queries in your add-ons. [Have a look at the database class.](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/database.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Channel Entries API to get those hooks to fire. You will never get them to fire using a query. http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html

Further more, you shouldn't even do it that way to begin with. CodeIgniter has an Active Record class to perform db queries. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Channel Entries API example

```
$this->EE->load->library('api');
$this->EE->api->instantiate('channel_entries');
$this->EE->api->instantiate('channel_fields');

$data = array(
        'title'         => 'Breaking News Story!',
        'entry_date'    => '1256953732',
        'edit_date'     => '1351653729',
        'field_id_6'    => 'Some data',
        'field_ft_6'    => 'none',
        'field_id_19'   => 'More data',
        'field_ft_19'   => 'xhtml'
);

$this->EE->api_channel_fields->setup_entry_settings($channel_id, $data);

if ($this->EE->api_channel_entries->submit_new_entry($channel_id, $data) === FALSE)
{
        show_error('An Error Occurred Creating the Entry');
}
```

Active Record Example:

```
 $results = $this->EE->db->query($sql);
 echo $results->row('field_id_34');
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question Justin. They're trying to *use* the hook via an extension - not *fire* it.

Comment: Indeed I did misunderstand, apologies.

Comment: I appreciate your responses. I had the wrong parameters in there as I was trying all the hooks that made sense and I did not notice the parameters changed. I have moved the hook to entry_submission_ready, which passes the entry_id, so I should now be able to make the query. I do plan on using the query classes, but for debugging purposes, I find this easier.

I still have the same result though after changing the hook to ..._ready. When I query the database on the entry_submission_ready hook, the resulting data is still the updated data.

Comment: I am basically trying to write an extension that, upon clicking the submit button in the control panel, can alert me of the change via email only if the field in question has changed. So I need to know what the value is currently, and what the user is attempting to change it to.

Comment: UPDATE: The purpose of this was to send an email if it is the first time the entry's status changes from open to cancelled. Since I couldn't get the hook to run as I expected, I chose to store the date the email is sent in a hidden field in the CP. So now I check two things on submission using the hook: make sure the hidden date field is empty and make sure the status is set to cancelled. If both are true, I update the hidden date field to the current timestamp. Now, in the future, if the entry is updated again, the hidden field is not blank, so the script does not send the email.

Comment: If all you need is to get an email when a status changes, you could try the MX-Notify-Control add-on by Max Lazar.